# Handling (in a servlet) an AJAX request to load JSP fragment into current JSP page

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

If I simply treat the request like a standard doPost... meaning, I just forward to the URL corresponding to my JSP fragment, will that fragment be loaded into the current JSP page by virtue of the fact that it is an AJAX request?  Or will it replace the original page like a regular full page request?

In order to load partial JSP into a current JSP page, must you use PrintWriter in the servlet (reading the JSP file line by line and writing it out)?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You seem to think that JSP/Servlet and JS/ajax run "in sync". This is not true. JSP/Servlet runs in webserver and produces HTML; JS/ajax runs in webbrowser and manipulates HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is right. You can treat an AJAX request exactly as another request, and execute a JSP that will generate a fragment of a page. The JavaScript function will receive this fragment, and can do whatever it wants with it: append it to some section of the page, replace a section with this fragment, etc.